# How to fix below mentioned errors

Tags: authentication, error-handling, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOvUN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU7JV.png)

how can i fix these errors?

I want to build login form in web using firebase but it gets an error

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.